# Location of a Hadoop job input file

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-data

I'm trying to generate a sequence file in my Spring batch job to be passed to a Hadoop map/reduce. I managed to get the job to work once by manually copying the file onto the hdfs. And when it's run in my local system test, it runs fine because the local filesystem finds the file. But when I attempt to deploy it to a remote Hadoop instance, I
get the following exception.

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://ngram-test:9000/user/hduser/DocumentsPTOgrants2007_2011.seq
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
    at com.atsid.hadoop.jobs.AbstractJobRunner.executeJob(AbstractJobRunner.java:70)
    at com.atsid.hadoop.jobs.AbstractJobRunner.run(AbstractJobRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at com.atsid.cloudbase.ngram.ingest.mapreduce.NGramIngestJobRunner.main(NGramIngestJobRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.JarExecutor.invokeTargetObject(JarExecutor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopCodeExecutor.invokeTarget(HadoopCodeExecutor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopCodeExecutor.runCode(HadoopCodeExecutor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.JarTasklet.execute(JarTasklet.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:386)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:250)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:293)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:349)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
```

Here's the tasklet configuration used by the step. I'm attempting to use the `files` attribute to pass the input file to the HDFS. The file is appearing in the Hadoop logs.

```
<hdp:jar-tasklet id="ingestJarTasklet" scope="step"
                 jar="file:${ingest.job.jar.path}"
                 main-class="com.atsid.cloudbase.ngram.ingest.mapreduce.NGramIngestJobRunner"
                 libs="${ingest.job.libs}"
                 files="#{seqFileLocation.URI.toString()}"
                 configuration-ref="hadoopConfiguration">
    ngram.jobrunner.input.document.sequence.file=${job.file.location}#{seqFileLocation.filename}
</hdp:jar-tasklet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your input path `/user/hduser/DocumentsPTOgrants2007_2011.seq` or you give `hdfs://ngram-test:9000/user/hduser/DocumentsPTOgrants2007_2011.seq`?

If you use the second one try the first one, and make sure that `DocumentsPTOgrants2007_2011.seq` is there.

You can have a look at whether it is there by this command: `hadoop dfs -ls ./`